# How well does the musical "Hamilton" conform to Aristotle's concept of mimesis?

Tags: theory, aristotle, hamilton-musical, lin-manuel-miranda

How does the musical *Hamilton* by Lin-Manuel Miranda reveal Aristotle's concept of *mimesis* (or *imitation*, from [*The Poetics*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1974/1974-h/1974-h.htm)), especially since it is a musical (which isn't very realistic at all?)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Apparently, some community members have downvoted your question without explaining why. The reason is most likely the speculative nature of the question: "What would Aristotle have thought ...?" This type of question is considered opinion-based. You can get around this by rewording to question by asking how well a specific musical conforms to Aristotle's concept of mimesis. That would make a fully adequate question for this site.